# cannot reference roomNumber before supertype constructor has been called

Tags: java, abstract-class, super

i have created two classes `Standard` and `Family` which extend abstract class `Room`, when compiling the `Standard` class i am met with the error "cannot reference roomNumber before supertype constructor has been called" but i cannot understand why, any help would be appreciated.

`Room`

```
public abstract class Room
{
    public int roomNumber;
    public String roomType;
    public boolean ensuite;
    public boolean available;

public Room(int roomNumber, boolean enSuite)
   {
       this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
       ensuite = enSuite;
       available = false;
   }
}
```

`Standard`

```
public class Standard extends Room
{
    private int roomNumber;
    private int childCap;
    private int adultCap;



public Standard(int theNumber, int kidsCap, int adultsCap)
   {
       super(theNumber, roomNumber);
       childCap = childsCap;
       adultCap = AdultsCap;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why did you redeclare roomNumber in the Standard class? I think that's the problem

Comment: PS this has a number of issues you may wish to clean up. The Standard constructor has two compile errors. You're passing roomNumber in place of "enSuite" as a param -- they're not even of the same type. Your "ensuite = enSuite" statement is confusing due to names differing by barely one letter case, using public fields is a no-no, and lastly hiding a public field with a private one in a subclass is bound to cause confusion!

Comment: Thanks guys, took a while but i understand what you meant and i have fixed the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super(theNumber, roomNumber);`

when calling a super constructor it must be the first thing you do. you're trying to send the private field roomNumber as a parameter.

on a side note, the Room constructor takes an int and a boolean value, while you are sending two ints.

`public Room(int roomNumber, boolean enSuite)`

Answer (score 3):

```
  super(theNumber, roomNumber);//both are int
```

When you write this, the compiler will search for a super constructor that has two `int parameter`, but there is no such constructor.  Your constructor has one `int` and one `Boolean`.

```
public Room(int roomNumber, boolean enSuite)
```

In Java **if the parent constructor can't make the call due to any condition, then the compiler should show it as an error.**

From [JLS-8.8.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1)

> An explicit constructor invocation statement in a constructor body may not refer to any instance variables or instance methods or inner classes declared in this class or any superclass, or use this or super in any expression; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
>   So change your constructor parameter or make a new one...

Answer (score 2):

you are referencing `roomNumber` in Standard, which is only processed by the JVM once the constructor of Room() has finished processing.  Class level variables are only processed and initialised by the JVM once the constructors of all superclasses have returned successfully.  So your call chain is something like:

Standard() -> Room() -> [ initialise Room's member variables] -> Return from Room() -> [initialise Standard's member variables]

As such, you cannot pass roomNumber up to Room, because in effect it will not yet exist.